# Sort index order with duplicate index numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

df1:

```
         Type         Number
24       variation     2.5
25       variation     2.6
26       variation      4
27       variation      4
```

dfn:

```
          Type         Number
24       variable
26       variable
```

I'm trying to append these two data frames and sort them by index

```
dfn = dfn.append(df).sort_index()
```

The end result should be

```
          Type         Number
24       variable
24       variation     2.5
25       variation     2.6
26       variable
26       variation      4
27       variation      4
```

However, I am getting results like:

```
          Type         Number
24       variable
24       variation     2.5
25       variation     2.6
26       variation      4
26       variable
27       variation      4
```

I want the row with variable type above the variation type, which works fine with the first index (24) but not for the next index (26) and so on. How can I get the desired results?

Comment: maybe you should reset_index, and sort values with index and Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try, append, reset index, sort values by multiple columns and drop the reset index column as follows

```
df1.append(dfn).reset_index().sort_values(['index','Type','Number']).drop('index',1)
```

Comment: Happy it did. Could you please upvote for the answer so that people with similar issues can confidently use your question and my answer for reference. I gave you an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
dfn = df.append(dfn).sort_index()
```